# Variables not working properly in python when creating triples

Tags: python, rdf

The idea is that I am taking in a Wordnet Text line, assigning all of the different parts of the line to different variables and entering those variable as triples into a RDFlib graph.

Here is a sample line from the text file:

`13797906 23 n 04 flood 0 inundation 0 deluge 0 torrent 0 005 @ 13796604 n 0000 + 00603894 a 0401 + 00753137 v 0302 + 01527311 v 0203 + 02361703 v 0101 | an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"`

Here is the code I have.

```
from rdflib import URIRef, Graph
from StringIO import StringIO

G = Graph()
F = open("new_2.txt", "r")
for line in F:

    L = line.split()
    L2 = line.strip().split('|')
    synset_offset = L[0]
    lex_filenum = L[1]
    ss_type = L[2]
    gloss = L2[1]                                   
    before_at, after_at = line.split('@', 1)
    N = int(L[3])
    K = int(before_at.split()[-1])                                     
    word = L[4:4 + 2 * N:2]                         
    iw = iter(word)
    S = after_at.split()[0:0 +4 * K:4]              
    ip = iter(S)
    SS = after_at.split()[1:1 + 4 * K:4]            
    iss = iter(SS)
    ST = after_at.split()[2:2 + 4 * K:4]          
    ist = iter(ST)

    line1 = '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#lex_filenum '''+lex_filenum+''''''
    line2 = '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#ss_type '''+ss_type+''''''             
    line3 = ''''''
    #line4 = '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss '''gloss'''                         
    for item in word: 
        line3 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#lexical_entry '''+iw.next()+'''\n'''   
    line5 = ''''''
    for item in S:
        line5 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+synset_offset+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#has_ptr '''+ip.next()+'''\n'''            
    line6 = ''''''
    for item in SS:
        line6 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+ip.next()+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos '''+iss.next()+'''\n'''                      
    line7 = ''''''
    for item in ST:
        line7 += '''http://www.example.org/lexicon#'''+ip.next()+''' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target '''+ist.next()+'''\n'''     

    contents = '''\
    '''+line1+'''
    '''+line2+''' 
    '''+line3+'''
    '''+line5+'''
    '''+line6+'''  
    '''+line7+''''''#'''+line4+'''

    tabfile = StringIO(contents)
    for line in tabfile:
        triple = line.split()
        triple = (URIRef(t) for t in triple)
        G.add(triple)

print G.serialize(format='nt')
```

It all works perfect until `line5`. (line4 is commented out for a different reason, I dont need it yet)

This is the error I get when I include line5, line6 and line7:

```
 G.add(triple)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib-4.1_dev-py2.7.egg/rdflib/graph.py", line 352, in add
    def add(self, (s, p, o)):
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I dont understand what the difference between line3 and line5 is that would cause an error, line3 works perfect!

Comment: why `ip.next()` and not `item`? Apparently you are making 2 iterators on S, one with ip, one with your for loop.

Comment: so change that to item.next()?

Comment: May be `S = after_at.split()[0:0 +4 * K:4]` is empty?

Comment: No because as i was creating the code i would print each list to make sure it worked,I dont think thats the problem

Comment: @Jonnerz : no. no need for item.next(). `item` is already the next item in the iterator on `S`. that's how loop on iterable works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `S = after_at.split()[0:0 +4 * K:4]` causes an empty value, meaning S is an empty list. Also, although you are iterating through all the items, in `for item in S`, item has not been used inside that loop!

Comment: I am after printing S there and all 5 values have come up in a list, The `for item in S` is just there so that the line gets printed as much times as the items that are in the list.

Comment: Or you can fire the following on the linux terminal `grep -v "@.\+" new_2.txt`. If you get some output, there is a problem with your input file.

Comment: if i leave out anything to do with line5, line6 and line7 it works fine!